# Laplace Transform of $e^{t^3}$

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

I have to find the Laplace transform of

$$e^{t^3}  u(t)$$

and I know that $u(t)$ will just change the integral from negative infinity to positive infinity to $0$ to positive infinity, but I'm stuck with what to do after that since $e$ is raised to a variable cubed. Help?

Comment: The LT of $e^{t^3}$ does not exist.

Comment: why doesn't it exist?

Comment: $e^{t^3-st}\to \infty$ as $t\to \infty$.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: try to find the expression for  $\int_0^\infty e^{a t^3} e^{-st} dt$ which clearly exists for any $Re(a) < 0$, and see if it makes sense to consider its analytic continuation for $Re(a) \ge 0$

Answer (score 1):

The **Laplace transform existence theorem** states that, if $f(t)$ is piecewise continuous on every finite interval in $[0,\infty)$ and there exist constants
$M$ and $a$ such that
$$|f(t)|\le M\mathrm e^{at} \qquad\text {for sufficiently large }t \in [0,\infty)$$ then 
$\mathcal L\{f(t)\}=F(s)$ exists for all $s>a$.

So, **a function $ f(t)$ has a Laplace transform whenever it is of exponential order**.

The function $\mathrm e^{t^3}$ is not of exponential order because
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\mathrm e^{t^3}}{M\mathrm e^{at}}=\infty\qquad\forall M,\, a\in\Bbb R
$$